# compiling gsoap sample hello service

Tags: c++, eclipse, gsoap

i downloaded gsoap 2.8.14, configure and install with the following commands:

```
./configure --disable-ssl --enable-samples --enable-debug
make
make install
```

im tried to compile gsoap sample "hello". so i took the the wsdl file from the sample and did the following:

```
wsdl2h -s -o hello.h h.wsdl
soapcpp2 hello.h
```

i copied the generated files into a new eclipse c++ project and excluded soapClientLib.cpp and soapServerLib.cpp because i was receiving errors like

> multiple definition of .....

i then created a helloserver.cpp and here is the content:

```
#include "soapH.h"
#include "Service.nsmap"

int main() 
{
  return soap_serve(soap_new);
}

int __ns1__hello(struct soap *soap, char* helloReq, char* &helloResponse)
{
  return SOAP_OK;
}
```

when i build in eclipse, i receives an error:

```
...soapServer.cpp:77 undefined reference to __ns1__hello(soap*,_ns2_hello*, _ns__helloResponse*)
```

when i trace to soapServer.cpp, this line is getting the error:

```
soap->error=__ns1_hello(soap,soap_tmp___ns1_hello.ns2__hello,&ns2__helloResponse);
```

why am i getting this error? im using the sample hello wsdl from gsoap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you can see from the error message (and the soapServer.cpp code) you are supposed to write a function

```
int __ns1__hello(struct soap *soap, 
    _ns2_hello* helloReq, 
    _ns__helloResponse* helloResponse)
{
  return SOAP_OK;
}
```

not the function you wrote.

Comment: oh yes john, i realise my mistake. it should not be char* data type. tks